# Disable android.hardware.foo feature to hide hardware from ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, hardware

Is it possible to tell an Android ROM (without recompiling it, but repacking is okay, I guess) that the device it runs on does not have a certain `android.hardware.something` feature?

I want to disable `android.hardware.telephony`, so that the ROM (CM11) does not start the telephony infrastructure (RILJ etc.) at all.